# How do I specify region in aws cloud formation command line tool for windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I submit this on command line (i'm omitting all the other params that i know to work)

`aws cloudformation create-stack ... --parameters ParameterKey=Region,ParameterValue=us-east-1`

It yields:

`Unable to construct an endpoint for cloudformation in region`**`None`**

If i submit the same exact params using the https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation web ui, it works.

How do i specify region using the aws.exe for windows ?    The .json file i use as a template even has it as the default, but it still does not take it if i omit region from the command line

"Region": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Which Region to launch in",
            "Default": "us-east-1",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "us-east-1", "us-west-1", "us-west-2", "eu-west-1", "ap-northeast-1"
            ]
        }

in debug mode i get...

```
File "awscli\clidriver.pyc", line 206, in main
File "awscli\clidriver.pyc", line 354, in __call__
File "awscli\clidriver.pyc", line 461, in __call__
File "awscli\clidriver.pyc", line 555, in invoke
File "botocore\service.pyc", line 161, in get_endpoint
File "botocore\endpoint.pyc", line 265, in create_endpoint
File "botocore\regions.pyc", line 67, in construct_endpoint
UnknownEndpointError: Unable to construct an endpoint for cloudformation in region None
2014-10-27 22:52:38,631 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The region is an argument of the aws command :

> aws --region eu-west-1 cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ...

Comment: Thanks.  Doing it from windows .bat file, i had arrived at this:

`aws cloudformation create-stack  `
--stack-name    %STACK_NAME%  
--capabilities  %CAPABILITIES%  
--template-url  %TEMPLATE_URL%  
--region        %global_region%  
--parameters    %PARAMETERS%

Comment: Sounds good. If the answer has been useful to you, please consider accepting it... :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also configure it using `aws configure` or if already executed you can identify it in `~/.aws/config`. Example:

```
[default]
region=us-east-1
```

The regions are as follows. See second column.

```
$ ec2-describe-regions
REGION  eu-central-1    ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  sa-east-1   ec2.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  ap-northeast-1  ec2.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  eu-west-1   ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  us-east-1   ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  us-west-1   ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
REGION  us-west-2   ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
REGION  ap-southeast-2  ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
REGION  ap-southeast-1  ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
```